# GPS location and sensor data in pydroid3

Tags: python, android, gps, pydroid

Does anyone know how to access GPS and phone sensor data with Pydroid3?

There's very little documentation online, and examples with plyer gps don't work. I'd like to read the light meter sensor, and GPS simultaneously with Pydroid script.

E.g. this code:

```
from plyer import gps

def print_locations(**kwargs):
    print('lat: {lat}, lon: {lon}'.format(**kwargs))

gps.configure(on_location=print_locations)
gps.start()
# later
gps.stop()
```

Fails with:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer.platforms.linux.gps'
Traceback (most recent call last):

I've also tried with plyer-s fork version from HyTurtle instead of main plyer